# Correct SQL usage in Python Using PYMYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4, pymysql

I am attempting to write a SQL in python using PYMYSQL, which searches a table for a certain record with a set value, however while this sounds simple I cannot seem to do it below is my query:

```
SELECT Series_ID FROM series_information WHERE Series_Name "'+data +'"'
```

where the data is the value that I am searching for however the following error occurs:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"Spice And Wolf"\' at line 1')
```

The problem I believe is that I am not sure how to properly escape the data value if it has spaces in it and therefore would require quotation marks in the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comparison (like, =, etc) between Series_Name and data, as well as a ';' on the end of the query.

`'SELECT Series_ID FROM series_information WHERE Series_Name = "'+data +'";'

Comment: Many thanks i guess the documentaiton i look at was wrong ;/ but thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT Series_ID FROM series_information WHERE Series_Name "'+data +'"'`
```

Is not a valid SQL query did you mean:

```
`'SELECT Series_ID FROM series_information WHERE Series_Name like "'+data +'"'`
```